# Ruby on rails model form pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm working on a RoR application. It has a heavy business model with a set of fields, which has something in common, and all are stored as id arrays serialized as JSON.
Now I'm implementing create form for that model. I already extracted validation functionality to a form object (with [reform gem](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)).
The problem is that all that fields (subjects to be serialized) have different representation on the view. Somewhere it should look like a set of checkboxes, somewhere - radiobuttons and so on.
Thus, I receive data in various formats from the view. What I do now - I have a number of before_filters in a controller, and I sanitize the data there. e.g. for checkbox groups I do stuff like

```
[:field_1, :field_2, :field_3].each do |param_name|
  params[:model][param_name] = params[:model][param_name].keys if params[:model].has_key?(param_name)
end
```

I'm not really satisfied with that approach.
What I'd like to have, is kind of a view component, which will encapsulate that logic. Is there a Rails way to perform that?

Thanks in advance!